# how to send text box value as parameter on form submit in mvc3 asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have created partial view in MVC3. now i want to send text box value as parameter of form submit on pressing the submit button

my partial view is like

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Searching", "AccountManager", FormMethod.Post, new { name ="Wat should i put here" }))
 {

   <input id="account" type="text" class="s" />
   <input id="Search" type="submit" class="b" value="hi" />

 }
```

and my controller is like

```
 public viewResult Searching(string name)
 {
   // bussiness logic
   return view();
 }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply give your textbox the same name as your action parameter argument:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Searching", "AccountManager")
{
    <input id="account" type="text" name="name" class="s" />
    <input id="Search" type="submit" class="b" value="hi" />
}
```

Now inside your controller action you will get the value entered by the user:

```
public ActionResult Searching(string name)
{
    // bussiness logic
    return View();
}
```